# rails 3.1.1 autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to get autocomplete working under Rails 3.1.

https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

I have been following this full app example and changing the relevant parts for Rails 3.1, but it's still not working.

https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-app

Here is my applicaion.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require_tree .
```

I've downloaded jquery 1.8.16 (with the autocomplete ticked), unzipped it and copied the js into my app/assets/javascript directory, and the css & images directory into app/assets/stylesheets.

I then made a link so I could reference it as jquery-ui

```
ln -s jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js jquery-ui.js
```

Same with the CSS

```
ln -s jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css jquery-ui.css
```

Then I put a link to my css in application.css

```
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require_tree .
```

I created the brand model & migrated and added seed data like the example.

I then added to my welcome controller the following line as per the tutorial:

```
 autocomplete :brand, :name
```

I fixed up the routes.rb file and edited the form.

What I get is the form with no autocomplete working, there are no errors in my server output either:

```
 % rails s -p 3001              
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3001
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-11-07 16:35:53] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-11-07 16:35:53] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-02-18) [x86_64-linux]
[2011-11-07 16:35:53] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=12616 port=3001


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-07 16:35:54 +1100
  Processing by WelcomeController#show as HTML
Rendered welcome/show.html.erb within layouts/application (15.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 98ms (Views: 75.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-07 16:35:55 +1100
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-07 16:35:55 +1100
Served asset /jquery-ui.css - 304 Not Modified (5ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-07 16:35:55 +1100
Served asset /jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css - 304 Not Modified (1ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-07 16:35:55 +1100
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)


Started GET "/assets/welcome.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-07 16:35:55 +1100
Served asset /welcome.css - 304 Not Modified (2ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-07 16:35:55 +1100
Served asset /jquery-ui.js - 304 Not Modified (5ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-07 16:35:55 +1100
Served asset /jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js - 304 Not Modified (3ms)


Started GET "/assets/welcome.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-07 16:35:55 +1100
Served asset /welcome.js - 304 Not Modified (2ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-07 16:35:55 +1100
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-07 16:35:55 +1100
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)


Started GET "/assets/autocomplete-rails.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-07 16:35:55 +1100
Served asset /autocomplete-rails.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
```

What am I missing here?
Is there a more up to date plugin for Rails 3.1 or a better tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it manually with the help of coffee-script and jquery-ui

Here are my notes in-case anyone else gets stuck: https://gist.github.com/1347080